# how to trigger file browse when i click on image/button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to trigger browsers file upload window when i click on custom button.Its should show same like below in the image.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here: [Custom file input can’t be that hard?](http://blog.anorgan.com/2010/02/07/custom-file-input-cant-be-that-hard/)

Or you can try something like this:

```
<div style='width:140px;margin-top:80px;position:relative;'>
    <div style='position:absolute; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; width:140px; height:20px; background:#3172a0; border-top:solid 1px #a2a2a2; color:#fff;padding-top:4px;' align='center'>Browse...</div>
        <input name='image' type='file' size='5' style='position:absolute; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; height:25px; opacity:0.01; filter:alpha(opacity=0); top:0px; left:0px;' />
    </div>
</div>
```